# How to auto resize width Bootstrap tooltip according to it's content, with line breaks

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I created a tooltip using Bootstrap.
I would like to display the tooltip with two lines How do I change the width of the tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to change the width of a tooltip, you can use the following CSS, changing `width:` to a value of your choice:

```
.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {width: 300px;}
```

If you wish to target only specific tooltips, you can add a custom class using `.myCustomClass +`:

```
.myCustomClass + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {width: 300px;}
```

This JSFiddle might help you: http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/2htze/

Hope this helped.